# What would be an easier way to update a Pygame display?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've recently tried teaching myself Python and I've made a app using Pygame to generate random stats for D and D enemies. 2 Questions. What would be a cleaner or better solution be for updating the Pygame display after clicking a button? Because currently I have the loop redefining the main window variable after every click in an attempt to get the stats to stay on the display.

```
if zombie.isOver(pos):
     win.fill((255, 255, 255))
     menu.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
     Zombie()
     pygame.display.update()
     x -= 1
     def drawWindow():
         again.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
```

After the button is pressed this gets redefined.

```
def drawWindow():
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    bandit.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    zombie.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    rat.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
```

I did this because the win.fill would cover up the values printed and I couldn't get them to stay any other way.

2nd question is when I mash the buttons in the display, 2 out of the 3 current ones work fine, however the 3rd button's values stutter and it is not smooth like the other 2. I think this is being caused by the location of the values in the code, they are the last ones I added putting them further down in the code, but honestly I have no idea.

```
if rat.isOver(pos):
     win.fill((255, 255, 255))
     menu.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
     Rat()
     pygame.display.update()
     x /= 2
     def drawWindow():
         again.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

if again.isOver(pos) and x == 5:
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    menu.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    again.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    Rat()
    pygame.display.update()
    def drawWindow():
        again.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
```

The button works the same as the other 2 but the values stutter. If anyone has an idea that would help it would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Are you updating the display every frame or just when the button is clicked?

Comment: This part, def drawWindow(): again.draw(win, (0, 0, 0)), Inside an if statement doesn't quite make sense as defining a function doesn't call it. I think the indentation seems off here

Comment: @The Big Kahuna I have it updating the display in the first few lines of the main While loop so I think that updates it every frame, it also updates it when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure if i completely understand how you are doing it but on way to do it is in the main loop, call `drawWindow()`. Which is this:

```
def drawWindow():
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    bandit.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    zombie.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    rat.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
```

I'm assuming that that is drawing images of them and not the stats. have a bool that controls whether to show the stats like `show_zombie_stats` for each of them. Then in the main loop or `drawWindow()`, you can do an if statement like

```
if show_zombie_stats:
     zombie.draw_stats()
```

then call `pygame.display.update()` at the end of the main loop.

Now you can change the `show_zombie stats` with the button with `show_zombie stats = not show_zombie stats`